# How to disable `git-rebase-mode` after magit is installed?

Tags: magit

I'd rather use regular text editing functions when rebasing instead of learning magit's bindings.

Is there a way to use magit but disable `git-rebase-mode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `git-rebase` from `auto-mode-alist`:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cl-remove-if (lambda (x) (eq (cdr x) 'git-rebase-mode))
                    auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: `(setq auto-mode-alist (rassq-delete-all 'git-rebase-mode auto-mode-alist))` works, without cl-lib.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer for completeness, when using `use-package`, this needs to be done from `:init`, eg:

```el
(use-package magit
  :init
  ;; Don't use magit for interactive rebase
  ;; (has own entire key-map, doesn't allow text-file editing).
  (setq auto-mode-alist (rassq-delete-all 'git-rebase-mode auto-mode-alist)))
```

Comment: Had to add the line inside `:config` rather than `:init`, because at least when used with `git-commit` mode, doing a `git commit --amend` adds the `'git-rebase-mode` back to the alist.